# Is Stack Overflow built with domain-driven design?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

I'm just curious. Is Stack Overflow built with [domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (or [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), etc.)?

Can you guys say something more about code infrastructure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Stack Overflow is built with Stack-Driven Design (SDD), a **new paradigm** and **revolutionary methodology** developed and promoted by **The Stack Overflow Team** (Web 2.0 moniker: *73 Stacks*).

Existing methodologies (including TDD, BDD, UDD, and WDD) tend to promote a myopic focus on one aspect of the development process, to the detriment of **The Whole Stack**. Stack-Driven Design eschews such primitive notions, opting instead for a multi-focus, metaphor-packed, fun-loving strategy referred to by SDD aficionados as **FPR Foci**.

SDD practitioners believe firmly in the old saying, **"The Proof is in the Syrup"**. Prior to SDD, software development success rates were notoriously difficult to evaluate accurately. SDD mandates a hard **6 to 8 week** development schedule, with the success of any project determined solely by its status at the end of this time frame. Though acolytes of other, lesser methodologies (where projects might run for months or even years) are often suspicious of this tactic, the delicious syrup proves them wrong: **all SDD projects complete successfully in 6 to 8 weeks**, no exceptions.

Comment: 73stacks.com isn't taken yet!

Comment: One of the few posts where bold is used the right way.

Answer (score 4):

[Looks like TDD is unlikely](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/4492867529).

Answer (score 4):

I think the methodology described by Jeff in his blog is called SOTP: Seat of the Pants.

It's quite common, and generally effective - provided what you're trying to do isn't too complicated, and you have sufficient time and talent.

While few people advocate SOTP as an enterprise SDLC methodology, it is in fact the de facto standard in many, if not most, organizations.

Sadly, most organizations do not have the time and talent enjoyed by SO...

Answer (score 3):

It's built with EDD, [Exception-Driven Design](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001239.html).